# Алгоритм визуализации дерева

Tags: c#, алгоритм, дерево

Как реализовать вертикальную иерархию дерева? Дерево - с произвольным количеством дочерних вершин. Узел дерева хранит условные координаты X, Y на плоскости. Под вертикальной иерархией, я подразумеваю, что узлы располагаются слева направо (т.е. слева - родитель, правее - дочерние узлы и т.д.)

За высоту каждого уровня думал брать сумму максимального количества узлов на подуровнях. Подскажите алгоритм или готовое решение, пожалуйста

Comment: Что значит "готовый алгоритм", готовый алгоритм существует только если вы для дерева используете более мнее извесную библиотеку. Например многие браузеры отображают xml-дерево.

Comment: Вы хотите отобразить дерево "вертикальная иерархия", зачем тогда `x` и `y`?. "За высоту каждого уровня думал брать" - нарисуйте себе пример дерева. И будет понятно какую высоту брать. Если "сумму максимального количества узлов" (наверно таки к-во). То наверное будет уже не совсем иерархия, а иерархия с нарастанием глубины.

Comment: @nick_n_a, да, типа иерархии с нарастанием глубины должно быть.  картинку здесь не могу прикрепить со схематичным изображением. Вот как обойти дерево, чтобы подсчитать высоту для родительского узла?

Comment: Как обойти - простейший метод - рекурсия. `int getDeep(ELM elm,int n){  if .... return getDeep(....., n+1); ....  return n }` что то такого типа.

Comment: @nick_n_a, я понимаю. Но у меня трудность в том, что я должен спуститься до самого последнего (дочернего) уровня. И на рекурсивном возврате получать количество дочерних узлов (высоту) для текущего уровня, тем самым резервируя место для высоты уровня. Вот как это реализовать? Каждый узел получается хранит список вершин, у которого есть свойство Count (количество дочерних узлов).

Comment: Я вам выше написал как. Рекурсивный вызов первой дочки (firstChild) и рекурсивный вызов следующего (nextSibling) Подсчёт через параметр. Более детально можно отобразить, только если есть структура классов. Думаю так `int getDeep(ELM e,int n){ if (e.firstChild) n=getDeep(e.firstChild,n); if (e.nextSibling) n=getDeep(e.nextSibling,n) return n+1; }` (условно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
    //узел дерева
    public class TreeNode
    {
        public TreeNode(string n)
        {
            this.Name = n;
            this.Children = new List<TreeNode>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; } //имя узла
        public int X { get; set; } //горизонтальная координата для отображения (заполняется TreeCalcCoordinates)
        public int Y { get; set; } //вертикальная координата для отображения (заполняется TreeCalcCoordinates) 
        public List<TreeNode> Children { get; set; } //список дочерних узлов
    }

    class Program
    {
        //получает суммарное количество всех дочерних узлов (высоту поддерева)
        static int GetChildrenCountSum(TreeNode node)
        {
            if (node.Children.Count == 0) return 1;

            int c = 0;

            foreach (TreeNode child in node.Children) c += GetChildrenCountSum(child);

            return c;
        }

        //получает максимальную ширину узла в дереве
        static void TreeGetMaxWidth(TreeNode root, ref int maxwidth)
        {
            if (root.Name.Length > maxwidth) maxwidth = root.Name.Length;

            foreach (TreeNode child in root.Children) TreeGetMaxWidth(child, ref maxwidth);

        }

        static void TreeCalcCoordinates_Recursive(TreeNode node, int basex, int basey, int dx)
        {            
            node.X = basex;
            node.Y = basey;

            int c = basey;
            foreach (TreeNode child in node.Children)
            {
                TreeCalcCoordinates_Recursive(child, basex + dx, c, dx);
                c += GetChildrenCountSum(child);                
            }
        }

        //вычисляет координаты узлов в дереве
        static void TreeCalcCoordinates(TreeNode root)
        {
            int maxwidth = 0;
            TreeGetMaxWidth(root, ref maxwidth);
            int dx = maxwidth + 1;            

            TreeCalcCoordinates_Recursive(root, 0, 0, dx);
        }

        static void TreePrint_Recursive(TreeNode node)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(node.X, node.Y);
            Console.Write(node.Name);

            foreach(TreeNode child in node.Children)
            {
                TreePrint_Recursive(child);
            }
        }

        //выводит дерево в консоль, используя вычисленные координаты
        static void TreePrint(TreeNode root)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            TreePrint_Recursive(root);
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //заполняем дерево тестовыми данными
            TreeNode root = new TreeNode("Животные");

            TreeNode node = new TreeNode("Млекопитающие");
            TreeNode node2 = new TreeNode("Хищные");
            node2.Children.Add(new TreeNode("Волк"));
            node2.Children.Add(new TreeNode("Лиса"));
            node.Children.Add(node2);
            node2 = new TreeNode("Зайцеобразные");
            node2.Children.Add(new TreeNode("Заяц"));
            node2.Children.Add(new TreeNode("Кролик"));
            node.Children.Add(node2);
            root.Children.Add(node);            

            node = new TreeNode("Птицы");
            node.Children.Add(new TreeNode("Пингвин"));
            node.Children.Add(new TreeNode("Попугай"));
            node.Children.Add(new TreeNode("Ворона"));            
            root.Children.Add(node);

            node = new TreeNode("Пресмыкающиеся");
            node.Children.Add(new TreeNode("Черепаха"));
            node.Children.Add(new TreeNode("Крокодил"));
            root.Children.Add(node);

            //вычисляем координаты
            TreeCalcCoordinates(root);

            //выводим дерево в консоль
            TreePrint(root);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, переделал под себя, то что нужно.